# Native iOS API for capturing panorama photos

Tags: ios, objective-c, panoramas

Since iOS 6 the Camera App has a builtin option for taking panoramic photos. From iOS 8 iPad has this option too.
Is there a way to use this native, builtin functionality in your own application? Does it have an API?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this panorama functionality is private API and we can't use it in our own apps.